# memoir class - Mixed portrait and landscape pages

Tags: memoir, landscape

Section 4.2.2. in [Notes on book design](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/memdesign/) makes a reference to mixed portrait and landscape pages.

I am aware of `pdflscape`, that allows such a mixing, but as this manual is written by the author of `memoir` I would assume that such a scenario should be achievable also using the built-in capabilities of the package itself.

I am unable to find any references in the main manual, and would appreciate any comments pointing me in the right direction, as I am sure I must have been overlooking this feature.

Comment: I don't think there's any specific functionality within `memoir` for this. But `pdflscape` is compatible with `memoir` so there should be no problem with using it.

Comment: @Alan: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: The [`pdflscape`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) package is maintained by [Heiko Oberdiek](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek), while the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class is maintained by [Lars Madsen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any specific functionality within `memoir` for this. But `pdflscape` is compatible with `memoir` so there should be no problem with using it.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that `memoir` and `pdflandscape` are compatible.

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter[Testing Mixed Orientations]{Testing Mixed Page Orientations}
\section{Portrait}
\lipsum

\begin{landscape}
\section{Landscape}
\lipsum
\end{landscape}

\section{Portrait Again}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: thumbnail gallery of compiled document]

Notice that although the middle pages are rotated from their normal orientation and the page text is upright, the page header is rotated, too.

Answer (score 3):

Should you want to rotate only the textblock, and leave the headers and footers in place, `xcoffins` can help. Here's a rather rough example, quickly adapted from a more complex piece of work involving a table:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{companion}
\begin{document}
\NewCoffin \stats
\SetVerticalCoffin \stats {\textheight}{%
    \lipsum[1-6]
% -------------------------------------------
\vspace*{0.5\onelineskip}
\captionof{table}{A tablefull of lipsum}
\label{tab:lips}
}
\RotateCoffin \stats {90}
\begin{table}
\raggedright
\noindent\TypesetCoffin \stats [t,r](0pt,\onelineskip)
\end{table}
\end{document}
```